# PlayerPrefs не сохраняет структуру

Tags: c#, c, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Ломаю голову не могу понять в чем дело , почему структура выдает везде Null  а остальное сохраняется !
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите код с изображения **текстом**. Код изображением это не есть хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Класс *Saves* и его структура не помечены атрибутом [Serializable].

Базовый юнитековский джейсон-сериализатор работает примерно так же, как сериализатор инспектора. Т.е. если вы хотите что-то сериализовать, то подходить нужно так же, как если бы вы хотели отобразить это поле в инспекторе монобеха.

Скорее всего, полям внутри структуры и самой структуре тоже понадобится добавить соответствующие атрибуты (структуре Serializable), а полям [SerializeField]

Документация [[Serializable]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html)
Документация [[SerializeField]](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html). По этой же ссылке можно прочитать о том, что юнити умеет сериализовать.